# Meteor.users.findOne works for console.log but not for publishing?

Tags: meteor

Im publishing my current user this this:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(
    { _id: this.userId },
    { fields: { groups: 1, name: 1 } },
  );
});
```

Its working but I belive that findOne is more efficient. The following console.log works but returning Meteor.users.findOne doens't work:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  const test = Meteor.users.findOne(
    {},
    { fields: { groups: 1, events: 1, name: 1 } },
  );
  console.log(test); // this works 

  // This doesn't work 
  return Meteor.users.findOne(
    {},
    { fields: { groups: 1, events: 1, name: 1 } },
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html) states that the publication should be either of 2 things:

1. A cursor
2. An array of cursors (of different collections)

> Publish functions can return a Collection.Cursor, in which case Meteor
>   will publish that cursor’s documents to each subscribed client. You
>   can also return an array of Collection.Cursors, in which case Meteor
>   will publish all of the cursors.

`findOne` returns a document. So I suppose it won't work.

Comment: OK. So do you know if this method is the recommended way of publishing the current user's profile fields?

Comment: I suppose. Since you are only returning the current user's document. Do you see any other user docs coming up in the console logs on the client? Also, maybe you could extend it to return other user's docs if you are an admin, who is in charge of moderating users. There was a very detailed write up pertaining to user profiles on meteor forums which I'm unable to find at the moment. I'll link it here when I find it.